# entropy of a system

Tags: entropy

If entropy of system can be directly linked to the amount of energy "unavailable" for doing useful work,and it is said to increase directly with an increase in temperature, what is this so-called "unavailable energy"?[considering the fact that temperature is an indication of kinetic energy of the molecules and kinetic energy is useful based on the fact that, it is the energy being transfered]

Comment: The problem with entropy is its concept of "useful" work - "unavailable energy" is energy that is only available to undo or reverse work that would be useful in the context, but what is and isn't useful is something defined entirely in relation to human purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Entropy does not increase directly with temperature, in fact the opposite is true. The concepts sprung up when looking at the efficiency of engines in particular the Carnot cycle. I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ER8d_ElMJu0&index=2&list=PLijqQiSMHnP2EEeM56zZAB2559-S7GYrg) video if you want to know the maths behind it. In short entropy $S$ is related to temperature in the following way.

$$dS=\frac{\delta Q}{T}$$

where $\delta Q$ is the change in heat energy. Thus the change in entropy is inversely proportional to the temperature and proportional instead to the heat coming out of the system. As you said kinetic energy is useful energy, but energy radiated into space as heat is unlikely to be used again.

Comment: Unlikely to be used again *by whom*? Presumably the universe still has a use for energy radiated into space - that is, energy radiated into space still participates in and continues to affect the behaviour of the entire physical system. The sun radiates energy into space and is clearly useful.

Comment: @Steve I realise I probably didn't phrase it well, but by use I mean the need for a temperature gradient for a system to do work , the more spread out energy becomes the less the overall gradient and the less it is able to do work, the suns energy is certainly useful to us, but how much use do we get out of the light from other stars?

Comment: you're alright, it's not that you've phrased it badly. I'm just making the point that *all* star energy is available to do useful work. The fact that the energy is not available on Earth or concentrated in a specific place doesn't mean that it becomes "less able to do work" in any systemic sense. All the energy emitted by a star before it's death is not lost - it simply does work elsewhere, including forming into new stars. Thermodynamics and it's claims about the "one-way"-ness of thermal energy, is based on superseded 19th century thought.

Comment: ...we have discovered since, for example, that gravity counteracts the spreading-out of energy.

Comment: @Steve that is true, what we call useful is just what's useful to us, but in the process of doing work elsewhere the overall entropy of the universe increases since energy is now more spread out, at some point this heat energy will be so spread out that the heat gradient will be the same everywhere and nothing will be able to happen.

Comment: That is interesting I wasn't aware of that

Comment: Consider the existence of black holes, that absorb gas, light, background radiation, and so on. It was not known in 19th century optics that gravity did bend light and electromagnetic radiation, because all that predates relativity - nor that black holes existed. The central claim in theormodynamics, of systems eventually reaching "thermal equilibrium", is best seen as theoretically defunct (like all classical physics is) that is only used for daily convenience in engineering (and only seems plausible because it approximates everyday observation).

Comment: I downvoted you because the statement "Entropy does not increase directly with temperature, in fact the opposite is true." requires an equation relating $dS$ and $dT$, not $dS$ and $T$. The appropriate equation is $dS=C/T\,dT$, where $C$ is the heat capacity and $T$ is the temperature. Since both of these are positive for stable, uniform materials, the entropy certainly increases with temperature for such materials.